# Updating the balancing factor of AVL tree nodes

Tags: data-structures, avl-tree

I am learning about AVL trees, and I know how to do all of the rotations, but the one thing I need to know is how to make it so that after each insertion or rotation the balancing factors of the nodes are updated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look at an existing AVL tree implementation. This is one I wrote originally for Hypersonic SQL, it is still used as part of my [H2 database](http://h2database.com):

[TreeNode](http://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/browse/trunk/h2/src/main/org/h2/index/TreeNode.java)
[TreeIndex](http://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/browse/trunk/h2/src/main/org/h2/index/TreeIndex.java)
[TreeCursor](http://code.google.com/p/h2database/source/browse/trunk/h2/src/main/org/h2/index/TreeCursor.java)

Comment: I am actually going to be writing about this in a tutorial as well.  Would this be violating intellectual property laws to check it out and then use what I learned in the tutorial?

Comment: As long as you don't copy the code 1:1 it's OK. The algorithm itself isn't protected. Of course you can also call the classes TreeNode TreeIndex TreeCursor, and the method names are not protected either. However, I suggest to re-write the Javadocs from scratch. As for the implementation, some methods are obvious. You don't really have much freedom as the algorithm is 'from the book', but I suggest to not just copy & paste the code for copyright reasons. You will also need your own test cases.